# io.swagger.jersey equivalents in swagger v3

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

Migration docs between swagger 1.5.0 and 2.1.11 seem to be basically non-existent.
Based on
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration

We have swapped out the old swagger-jersey2-jaxrs dependency for

```
<!--    <dependency>-->
<!--        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>-->
<!--        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>-->
<!--        <scope>compile</scope>-->
<!--    </dependency>-->

      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.11</version>
      </dependency>
```

However the io.swagger.jersey classes don't seem to have equivalents, particularly between swagger-jersey2-jaxrs and swagger-jaxrs2.

Does anyone know where these went or if there's alternative documentation I should be reading?